# Computing greatest common divisor and determining whether Diophantine equation has solutions

Tags: divisibility, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

Question:

(1) Compute gcd$(224, 12 + 2^{10})$

(2) Describe in words the set of all integers $ n$ for which the equation $ \ 4x + ny = 1$ has integer solutions.

(3)

Describe in words the set of all integers $ \ n$ for which the equation $ \ 3x + ny = 1$ has integer solutions.

My attempt:

For (1) the Euclidean algorithm will be difficult to use. Should I use the theorem that states gcd$ \ (a,b) = $ gcd($ a -bq, b)$ or should I prime factorize both sides? I am not quite sure.

For (2) we need need gcd$(4,n) = 1$ in order for the equation to have integer solutions. This means that $ \ n$ must belong to the set of all odd integers.

For (3) we need need gcd$(3,n) = 1$ in order for the equation to have integer solutions. This means that $ \ n$ must belong to the set of all integers that are not divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

$224= 4\cdot 7\cdot 8$ and $12+2^{10} = 4(3+2^8)=4\cdot 7\cdot 37$.

So $gcd(224,12+2^{10}) =28$.

The rest is fine.

Ok, ok, we can factor $$2^8+3 = 2^8-2^2+4+3= 2^2(2^6-1)+7 = 4(2^3-1)(2^3+1)+7 =4\cdot 7\cdot 9+7 = 7(36+1) =7\cdot 37$$

Comment: It'd help to say how you factored $\,3+2^{\large 8}\,$ (no nontrivial factorization is needed if we use Euclid's algorithm).

Comment: I did not factor it, i just calculated it and then divide it with 7

Comment: I am not allowed to use calculators.

Comment: Well i did it without calculator.

Comment: I just edit it.

Comment: @john Ah, so you're essentially doing as I did, taking the gcd with the factors of $224$.It'd be clearer to explicitly explain that.

Answer (score 1):

$(224,12\!+\!2^{10}) = 4(7\cdot 8,\,3\!+\!2^8)= 4\cdot 7\ $ by  $\ \begin{align}\\ &\overbrace{(8,3\!+\!\color{#0a0}{2^8}) = (8,3)=1}^{\large\quad\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{2^{\Large 8}}\,\equiv\, 0\pmod{8}}\\ &\underbrace{(7,3\!+\!\color{#c00}{2^8}) = (7,3\!+\!2^2)}_{\large\quad\ \ \ \color{#c00}{2^{\Large 7}}\,\equiv\, 2\pmod 7}=7\end{align}$

---

Or use $\,{\rm mod}\ 224\!:\,\ 2^{\large 8} = 256\equiv 32\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{10}\equiv 4\cdot 32,$ and use Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: I am not familiar with  mod operation. I was taught the Euclidean algorithm by repeatedly using the division algorithm.

Comment: @Josh I used $\ (a,b) = (a,b')\,$ if $\,a\mid b-b',\,$ i.e. if $\, b\equiv b'\pmod a,\,$ i.e. Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it by repeatedly using the division algorithm?

Comment: @Josh $\ a\mid b-b'\Rightarrow\, b = qa + b'\,$ so $\, (a,b) = (a,\,qa+b') = (a,b')\,$ in division language.  The common form of Euclid's algorithm chooses $\,b' = b\bmod a =\,$  remainder of $\, b\div a,\,$  i.e. the *least* possible such $b'$ that is $\ge 0$ (but that is not always the most convenient choice).

Comment: Oh I see. I understand now. Is my argument for part b and part c correct?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Almost: we need to employ $\rm\color{#c00}{both}$ directions of the Bezout equivalence,  i.e. we need to use that $\,mx+ny = 1\,$ is solvable in integers $\,x,y\color{#c00}{\iff} (m,n) = 1\ \ $

Comment: Do you mean gcd(m,n) = 1?

Comment: How can I modify my current argument?

Comment: @Josh  e.g. in $(2)$ you make the inference that if it is solvable then $\, (4,n) = 1\,$ so $\,n\,$ is odd. But that does not imply it is solvable for *all* odd $n$. For that we need the reverse direction, i.e. if $n$ is odd then it is solvable. Only using *both* directions can we conclude that it is solvable $\iff n$ is odd. Similarly for $(3)\ \ $

Comment: How about this. The equation has integer solutions if and only if $ \ n$ belongs to the set of odd integers.

Comment: @josh That's true, but you need to deduce it correctly from Bezout.

Comment: So, an equation of the form $ \ ax + by = 1$ has integer solutions $ \iff$ gcd(a,b) = 1. Hence, the given equation has integer solutions $ \iff \ n$ belongs to the set of odd integers.

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Correct.

Comment: So now my argument is valid right?

Comment: Yes, if you phrase it in that "if and only if" form then the argument is correct and complete.